# Generate the SVG with constant size by python-qrcode

Tags: python

I am working for an app, which will generate the SVG file. I am using [python-qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode). But the problem is that this generates the SVG file with the size of depending on string size.

```
import qrcode
import qrcode.image.svg

currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
getfileName = currentTime.replace(':', '_').replace(' ', '_')

fileName = "qrcodes/" + getfileName + '.svg'

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
img = qrcode.make( url, image_factory=qrcode.image.svg.SvgImage)
img.save( fileName )
```

Now if you try long string in URL. then the image of size will be large than the current one.

I want to the SVG file with constant size.

Comment: Is it the `box_size` parameter you're looking for? From the docs: The box_size parameter controls how many pixels each "box" of the QR code is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the number of pixels in the QR code using the `version` parameter to the `make` function. From the docs:

> The `version` parameter is an integer from 1 to 40 that controls the
>   size of the QR Code.

So in your case, you can do:

```
img = qrcode.make( url, image_factory=qrcode.image.svg.SvgImage, version=10)
```

Comment: `box_size` does not solve the problem. It is generating large SVG for the long string.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Try the `version` parameter instead. I think it would still not prevent your QR code from being larger if your input gets too large for the version though.

Comment: It seems that SVG size will be based on string size :(